# When using JQuery, why add properties to events (click.myFunc, scroll.myFunc, resize.myFunc etc)

Tags: jquery

I'm looking over some scripting that has .Scrolling as properties of JQuery events:

```
$(window).on({
        'click.Scrolling' : function( event ) {
            //stuff
        },  
        'scroll.Scrolling' : function( event ) {
            //stuff
        }
    });
```

Is the ".Scrolling" just a property that this coder added for readability? If I remove the ".Scrolling,"  the page still operates the same.

Comment: It is a namespace, usefull when you want to unbind/trigger specific handlers http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/  e.g http://jsfiddle.net/ywgpB/

Comment: Thanks for the helpful links roasted.  So, the original coder never referenced click.Scrolling or scroll.Scrolling, but he now has the option to specifically handle those events in the future.